# Sorting NSDates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdictionary

i have several dictionaries in my program,i have put all those dictionaries in an array i want to sort those dates accordingly dictionary should exchange its position,below shown is the code i am using,but i am not getting it sorted.Please help me to fix this issue

**NSLog(@"before sorting---%d",[allDataArray count]);

```
for(int i=0;i<[allDataArray count]-1;i++){
    NSString *dateStr1=[[allDataArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Date"];
    for(int j=i+1;j<[allDataArray count];j++){
        NSString *dateStr2=[[allDataArray objectAtIndex:j]objectForKey:@"Date"];
        if(([(NSDate*)dateStr1 compare:(NSDate*)dateStr2]==NSOrderedAscending)
           ||([(NSDate*)dateStr1 compare:(NSDate*)dateStr2]==NSOrderedSame))
            [allDataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[allDataArray objectAtIndex:j]];
    }
}
   NSLog(@"afterSorting-numbers--%@",allDataArray);**
```

Comment: If that's supposed to be a bubble sort it isn't.  You're not swapping the two entries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you're reinventing the wheel here (sorting has been solves decades ago), do this instead:

```
NSArray *allDataArray = ...;
NSArray *sortedAllDataArray = [allDataArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Date" ascending:YES]]];
```

or this:

```
NSArray *allDataArray = ...;
NSArray *sortedAllDataArray = [allDataArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *dict1, NSDictionary *dict2) {
    return [[dict1 objectForKey:@"Date"] compare:[dict2 objectForKey:@"Date"]];
}]
```

Comment: @karthick: Great, glad I could help! Btw, as this is your first question on StackOverflow, lemme just introduce you to something neat: you can accept the best answer to your question as "correct" in order to mark your question as solved and by that allow you and other future visitors to search for valid solutions for a specific problem on StackOverflow more efficiently. Solved questions show up with a yellow "n answers" label in search results or listings. To accept an answer there's a checkmark on the left next to each answer that turns green upon clicking. Anyway, have fun on StackOverflow!

Comment: Thank u Regexident,for letting me know.