# How to sort an array containing NSDates

Tags: ios, arrays, sorting

Can you help me on sorting (ascending order) the array contains `NSDate`.

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[tempArray addObject: NSDate1];
[tempArray addObject: NSDate2];
[tempArray addObject: NSDate3];
[tempArray addObject: NSDate4];
```

Comment: You should do something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8136413/1915443

Comment: Thanks so much, it works fine

Comment: Check out these links : [link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354753/sorting-an-nsarray-of-nsdates) [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913377/sort-array-of-objects-by-their-nsdate-property) [link 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083408/sort-nsarray-of-custom-objects-by-their-nsdate-properties) [Google search](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sort%20nsdate%20array)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374040/objective-c-sort-string-date-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting NSDates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136367/sorting-nsdates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code:

```
  [your array sortUsingComparator:
  ^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){

         obj1 *o1 = (obj1*)obj1;
         obj2 *o2 = (obj2*)obj2;
         if (o1.personAge > 02.personAge) {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
        }


        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}
```

];

Answer (score 1):

Since `NSDate` responds to `compare` and the default sorting order is ascending, the simplest way is

```
[tempArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSSortDescriptor *dateSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self.dueDate" ascending:YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSDate *date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:obj1];
    NSDate *date2 = [dateFormat dateFromString:obj2];

    return [date1 compare:date2];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this,use sort descriptor.

```
 NSSortDescriptor *dateSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self.dueDate" ascending:YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDate *dateObject1, NSDate *dateObject2) {

return [dateObject1 compare:dateObject2];
}];
```

Comment: That sorts actually strings (NSString) rather than dates (NSDate)

Comment: No @vadian we converting the date string to date and then comparing the dates. If you already have two dates then just compare it date1 compare:date2

Comment: The question **is** about `NSDate` objects.

Comment: @vadian i edited the method please check let me know the problem if not done by this snippet of code.

Comment: Basically it's correct now. But the question is also about sorting an `NSMutableArray` of dates rather than dictionaries or custom objects with a key `dueDate`.

Answer (score 0):

```
[array1 sortUsingComparator: (NSComparator)^(NSString *key1, NSString *key2)
 {        
     return [key2 compare: key1];
 }
 ];
```

If you want array in ascending or descending order just change

> compare

```
return [key1 compare: key2];
```